# Do water droplets falling from the sky product roughly pi total waves?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, water

So I was making an observation outside while it was raining on my porch, the droplets roughly made 3 total cycles of waves. I made a hypothesis that the total wavelength from beginning to end might be pi. Then I thought, well  if a droplet is roughly a sphere, wouldn't it make a total pi wavelength? But then I asked myself, why would the water on the ground "know" anything about some kind of standard length. Then it hit me that the radius is intrinsic to the droplet. I'm not sure if I'm making anything up or not, I'm assuming the droplets velocity is uniform. Does anyone know if this is true, that a standard water droplet leaves a total wavelength of pi or is it just roughly three?

Comment: Not sure what the wave is you are talking about (care to elaborate?), but its wavelength will definitely not be $\pi$ for a wavelength has dimension length (and a unit like meters) whereas $\pi$ is dimensionless.

Comment: The length of the first wave added with the 3 other waves was the total I was talking about. With one wave cycle equaling one. Basically one sine wave, or cosine, seeing as how it's level with the ground.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was just a coincidence that there were about 3 waves crest from crest. I am curious however if there's an equation that factors in velocity and volume of the droplets that estimates how many wavelengths total there are when water strikes a pool of water.

Comment: It's still unclear what waves you are talking about, as in where are you seeing this wave.